# How to use Postman

Tags: curl, postman

I'm using this CURL line for my test:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: U2FsdGVkX1/AT1TyraJ0as+h6nu0hW4fvl" -X PUT -d "{\"\$set\":{\"product\":\"Product New Name\" ,\"quantity\":90}}" http://localhost:3000/api/RDiHJAbxpjFqeA9aC
```

I would like to use Postman. How to achieve the same from Postman?

Comment: error import curl see :
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use to fix your problem from version 4.4.3 onwards. This error is controlled.
4.4.0 - 4.4.3 22

Added support for --url as a cURL parameter

Comment: Thanks @behrouzMoslem

Answer (score 0):

Waiting close issue at : 
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1831

its bug on postman.